# Bootstrap carousel makes fixed background jump in Chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome, bootstrap-4, carousel

I am using bootstrap v 4.1.0 with the following setup:

```css
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.carousel-item {
  max-height: calc(30vh);
}

.pos-rel {
  position: relative;
}

.container-breaker {
  position: relative;
  left: calc(-49vw + 50%);
  width: 99vw;
}

.fixed-bg {
  background: url('http://www.jesslaversdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/test-image-750x500px.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  min-height: 25rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="header-carousel">
  <div id="carouselLRIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselLRIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselLRIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Stripes_scaling_test_image_orig.png" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Stripes_scaling_test_image_orig.png" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="pos-rel">
    <div class="container-breaker">
      <div class="fixed-bg">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Asmodis/3sya10cz/) just for the case that the images do not load in the integrated snippet viewer.

The following only happens in Google Chrome so I am not 100% sure whether it is a problem with Chrome, bootstrap or my own stuff:

Whenever the carousel image moves, the background in the .fixed-bg div jumps a bit to the right (it seems to align with the .container border for the time that the carousel is moving). In some other setup that I am unfortunately unable to reproduce right now, it even made the whole background disappear for some time.

What I found out so far:

- When I remove the `background-attachment: fixed;`, the background does not seem to jump anymore but I would really like to keep it.
- As already mentioned: Chrome seems to be the only affected browser - Firefox and Edge work as expected.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it seems to be a lot better. Let me know if it works in your particular instance

**HTML**

```
<div class="header-carousel">
  <div id="carouselLRIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#carouselLRIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#carouselLRIndicators" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active"> 
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Stripes_scaling_test_image_orig.png" alt="First slide">
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="d-block w-100 img-fluid" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f6/Stripes_scaling_test_image_orig.png" alt="Second slide">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="pos-rel">
    <div class="container-breaker">
      <div class="fixed-bg">
        test
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}

.carousel-item {
  max-height: calc(30vh);
}

.pos-rel {
  position: relative;
}
.container-breaker {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.fixed-bg {
  background: url('http://www.jesslaversdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/test-image-750x500px.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
  min-height: 25rem;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: So you only replaced

      `left: calc(-49vw + 50%);
      width: 99vw;`
by 
    `width: 100%;`
?

Unfortunately that does not help because it changes the whole appereance of the container. My version covers the whole width of the viewport whereas your version only covers the width of the .container.